# How do I get my API with django-cors-headers working without 405 error

Tags: django, django-cors-headers

I can't find my answer in other posts about CORS and django. So I am asking my question here after a full day figuring out what I am doing wrong.

my frontend is VUE.js and this app is making this API call to my backend on a DigitalOcean.com app server with Django and djangoRestFramework.

```
fetch( 'https://someurl.ondigitalocean.app/api/user/token',
            { method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               },
              body: JSON.stringify({ email: 'emai@email.com', password: 'password' }),
            },
           ).then(function(response){
                    if (response.ok){
                      return response.json()
                    }
                  }).then(function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                            }
                          )
```

This does a post to receive a token. This call is just for testing purpose. The API is working, for testing I use the default django browser interface and also all my units tests are OK.

I am using django-cors-headers as Middleware and added corsheaders to my 'APP' and 'MIDDLEWARE'' in my settings file.

these are my settings:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://maf-internet.nl",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://maf-internet.nl",
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True


CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]
```

These are my packages:

```
Django>= 2.2, <2.2.2
djangorestframework>=3.9.0,<3.10.0
psycopg2-binary
dj-database-url
gunicorn
django-cors-headers>=3.7.0
flake8>=3.6.0,<3.7.0
```

Digital Ocean also has an entry for CORS origin. I have added the front-end domain here and the result is still the same. Here you see my error 405.

[image: error API call]

I just don't see what I am doing wrong. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had to protect the client domain with https. I did not know, and for testing I thought it would be fine to use a HTTP domain. Wrong! You need an Https domain to talk to django-rest-framework and django-cors-headers on DigitalOcena app's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) library to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

tried `pip install django-cors-middleware` and worked for me without having to do any thing , just make sure you have  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE